# CSS Validation Problem

Tags: css, validation

I have a script which dynamically creates CSS. Currently, the CSS is not loaded in the head section, but is loaded in the middle of the document.

I receive this error at validation service:

> Element link is missing required attribute itemprop.

This is the line error:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylemaker.php?loadstyle=65456465' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

What are the potential causes of this problem?

Comment: Style sheet links in the `body` tag are not valid in HTML - you need to put the element into the `head` section

Answer (score 1):

`itemprop` is an HTML5 attribute for adding [microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html) to your elements. It is not necessary.

Comment: but isn't validating. what can I do?

Comment: @greenbandit: Ignore the warning? It's not a fatal flaw.

Answer (score 1):

And if you can't move it into the head (for whatever reason), you can always load it dynamically using jQuery like so...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylemaker.php?loadstyle=65456465" type="text/css"  media="all" />');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to validate if the css is within the body tag move

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylemaker.php?loadstyle=65456465' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

to the head section